# vm_compressor_mode (vm.compressor_mode) values for enabled compressed memory in OS X

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory, memory-pressure

### Background

In Super user, with an [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/681252/84988):

- [**Disable** compressed memory in Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks?](https://superuser.com/q/668114/84988)

Also in Super User:

- [how to get memory compress back in Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks?](https://superuser.com/q/701759/84988)

– and from the first answer there we understand that the value of *boot argument* `vm_compressor` does not correspond with the value of *sysctl variable* `vm.compressor_mode`.

In Apple open source for OS X 10.9, Mavericks; in xnu-2422.1.72:

- [vm_compressor.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/vm/vm_compressor.c)
- [vm_fault.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/vm/vm_fault.c)
- [vm_pageout.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.h)

In vm_compressor.c:

```
/*
 * vm_compressor_mode has a heirarchy of control to set its value.
 * boot-args are checked first, then device-tree, and finally
 * the default value that is defined below. See vm_fault_init() for
 * the boot-arg & device-tree code.
 */
```

On a MacBookPro5,2 with 8 GB memory I find:

```
sh-3.2$ sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode
vm.compressor_mode: 4
```

Near the foot of vm_pageout.h:

```
extern int vm_compressor_mode;
extern int vm_compressor_thread_count;

#define VM_PAGER_DEFAULT                0x1 /* Use default pager. */
#define VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP         0x2 /* In-core compressor only. */
#define VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP           0x4 /* In-core compressor + swap backend. */
#define VM_PAGER_FREEZER_DEFAULT            0x8 /* Freezer backed by default pager.*/
#define VM_PAGER_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP     0x10    /* Freezer backed by in-core compressor only i.e. frozen data remain in-core compressed.*/
#define VM_PAGER_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP       0x20    /* Freezer backed by in-core compressor with swap support too.*/

#define VM_PAGER_MAX_MODES              6   /* Total number of vm compressor modes supported */

#define DEFAULT_PAGER_IS_ACTIVE     ((vm_compressor_mode & VM_PAGER_DEFAULT) == VM_PAGER_DEFAULT)

#define COMPRESSED_PAGER_IS_ACTIVE  (vm_compressor_mode & (VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP | VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP))

#define DEFAULT_FREEZER_IS_ACTIVE   ((vm_compressor_mode & VM_PAGER_FREEZER_DEFAULT) == VM_PAGER_FREEZER_DEFAULT)

#define DEFAULT_FREEZER_COMPRESSED_PAGER_IS_ACTIVE      (vm_compressor_mode & (VM_PAGER_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP | VM_PAGER_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP))
```

## Question

Is it possible to have an **enabled** mode other than 4 for [compressed memory](https://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/#memory)?

If so, can we find a plain english explanation of the modes?

Comment: The header file you quote seems to state that both modes 2 and 4 means that the compressed pager is enabled. Therefore I'm a bit puzzled by your question - do you mean that you have actually tried mode 2, and it didn't enable compressed memory?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175572/23761

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely certain of the FREEZER options, other than one FREEZER_COMPRESSOR option uses swap (utilizes free space on a disk) when RAM is low or expended, while the other does not.

What I think is that the FREEZER options are for managing memory for frozen processes. Maybe this is something experimental, to be used in combination with App Nap? I think this was something they were testing with iOS a few years back.

What I know is that option 1 uses no compression, and is the old fashioned OS X memory management we're all more familiar with. If you're having issues you suspect are related to memory compression, you might try this setting.

Option 2 uses compressed memory with no swap (no writing to disk when RAM is low or expended).

Option 4 uses both compression and swap.

Option 8 uses whatever the FREEZER is, backed by the option 1 implementation.

Comment: Is there actual documentation on what the FREEZER does?

Comment: It’s interesting that the edit to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175572/ says Apple responded to a radar or feedback or support case and the traditional option 1 is known to fail in some cases and is no longer a supported mode.

Comment: @bmike That makes sense, given the timeline, here. I've since moved to Linux + LXDM + Openbox, with heavy, but reusable, customization, as I wanted more control over my operating system and working software environment, as opposed to the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Can't add a comment, so I'll write as answer:
Looks like freezer is Apple's patented [technology](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2016/0357478.html) and if you'll use `VM_PAGER_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP` it shouldn't use the compressor [too?](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a449c6a3b8014d9406c2ddbdc81795da24aa7443/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.c#L4420) (see, compressor is present, but isn't activated)

Answering the question, you can have:

1. VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP - compressed memory + swap
2. VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP   - compressed memory w/o swap
3. VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP_PLUS_FREEZER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP - compressed memory + freezer's swap