# Disable swapping on Yosemite

Tags: macos

Under OS X Mavericks and below we just could `launchctl unload` the dynamic_pager plist, but trying to unload this plist doesn't have any effect since OS X Yosemite.

What is the new way to disable swap files now with OS X Yosemite?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42453/discussion-on-question-by-bwoebi-disable-swapping-on-yosemite).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
# Check installed RAM, disable VM if 8Gb or more.

mem_inst=`/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.memsize`

if [ "$mem_inst" -ge "8589934592" ]; then
    echo "8Gb+ Memory installed."
        if [ "$action" == "unload" ]; then
            sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=2"
            sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
            echo "vm.compressor_mode set to 2"
        else
            sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=4"
            sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3
            echo "vm.compressor_mode reset to defaults"
        fi
            launch_control $action /System/Library/LaunchDaemons com.apple.dynamic_pager
    else
    echo "Less than 8Gb memory."
fi
```

This isn't something I wrote, was information I found.

Comment: I just tried to use `sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=2"`, which might definitely be the correct solution, when looking at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/118839/97060. I applied that command and rebooted. Will accept if there's still no swap in a few hours, just to verify ;-) (By the way, everything else in this post except that single command are useless commands...)

Comment: For followers, vm_compressor 2 is VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_NO_SWAP and 4 is VM_PAGER_COMPRESSOR_WITH_SWAP (ref: www.apple.stackexchange.com/q/118839/25085). On sierra I get `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error` unless disabling system integrity protection first, then it works

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do:

sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
*(disables hibernation mode)*

sudo rm -rf /private/var/vm/*.*
*(removes existing swap files)

sudo chflags uchg /private/var/vm/
*(locks down the swapfile directory, prevents anything from being written to the folder)*

**As others have said, though, please only do this if you know what you're doing.**

Comment: Which basically works too, but isn't the _clean way_. It just writes messages in the log files etc.. Just use `sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=2"` and you're fine.

Comment: I should have said "Here's what I've done in the past"

Between SSDs and a ton of RAM, I no longer choose to disable swap.  It's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: According to http://wiki.summercode.com/how_to_disable_or_enable_swapping_in_mac_os_x you should do some launchctl thing first?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist
```

Tested on freshly installed Yosemite from App Store.

Comment: Getting `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist: Could not find specified service
`. Also it doesn't have any effect on whether the system is swapping or not. (yes, I did reboot)

Comment: on sierra, requires you to "disable system integrity protection first" FWIW

Answer (score -2):

I used a program called Onyx to disable my swap file.
& I have 16GB of RAM.