# Is there any way to prevent a MacBook Air (2019) from powering up when an input device (keyboard or trackpad) is touched or the lid is open?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, mojave

#### While I know there is a hack to prevent MacBooks — 2018 and higher — from starting up when the lid is open, I would like to know if there is a similar hack to prevent a MacBook from powering up when an input device (keyboard or trackpad) is touched *or* when the lid is open.

I have a MacBook Air (2019) that is running macOS 10.15.4 (Catalina) and it seems to do something that owners of 2016 and newer MacBook Pros mention experiencing: After fully shutting down the machine, the second you open up the lid of the MacBook, the MacBook boots up without hitting the power button.

This isn’t a completely annoying issue, but I find it to be a bit odd. I have [read blog posts like this one](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/19/disable-boot-on-open-lid-macbook-pro/) — as well as this [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/276040/40457) post — that recommends modifying the NVRAM like this:

```
sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00
```

And to unwind that you can run this command or reset the NVRAM completely:

```
sudo nvram AutoBoot=%03
```

But when I did this, while the machine definitely did not initially boot up when the lid was open, pressing any key on the keyboard — and even the trackpad — will make my 2019 MacBook Air start up. So my question is [similar to that other Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/276040/40457) but I am also asking about the issue where the machine will start up if a keyboard key or the trackpad is pressed.

This seems weird to me: Why have a power button when *any* touch of an input device will start the thing up?

#### Is there any way to prevent a MacBook Air (2019) that has been fully shut down — and possibly 2018 and newer MacBook Pros — from powering up when an input device (keyboard or trackpad) is touched or the lid is open?

Just let me be able to power it up the good old fashioned way by pressing the power button (with Touch ID) that is in the upper right-hand corner of the keyboard.