# How to disable auto boot in MacBook Pro when the lid is opened?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

My new MacBook Pro powers on automatically when the laptop lid is opened.

Can I disable it ? If yes, then how to do it ?

Comment: @mmmmmm ok. wait updating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This article](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/19/disable-boot-on-open-lid-macbook-pro/) has the info for you.

Steps :

1. Open the Terminal from this location `/Applications/Utilities/`
2. Enter the command - `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00` to turn off autoboot feature.
3. Hit <kbd>return</kbd> and authenticate with the admin password (necessary due to sudo).
4. Exit terminal when finished

Note : If you want to reset to defaults, then enter this command - `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%03`

Comment: Can I do without terminal ?

Comment: Nope. So far as I know, the only way to modify nvram settings is through Terminal.

Comment: If I want to revert back,  then what will be the command ?

Comment: It does the trick but please notice that, as mentioned in this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295385/233929) it does not prevent the machine to boot.

Comment: While this may work for Intel Macs, this does not work for M1 Macs, and the only nvram setting there is `auto-boot`, not `AutoBoot`. `auto-boot` is set to `true` by default, but setting it to `false` will cause the Mac to be unbootable. I have not found a way to prevent boot on lid open on an M1 Mac.

Answer (score 10):

**Update :**

*For those who are using **Intel Chip based Macbook Pro/Air laptops** (on/before 2019) :*

> This command `sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00` will partially disable the
> autoboot only when the lid is opened.
> But there is a limitation to that. If you press any key or touch the trackpad, it will start booting up which is kind of annoying.

*For those who are using **Apple M1/M2 Chip based Macbook Pro/Air laptops** (from 2020 onwards) :*

> Unfortunately, Apple team didn't add the feature of turning off the
> autoboot for Apple M1/M2 Chip MacBooks. We have to wait until any new
> update comes for M1/M2 Chip which includes turning off the autoboot.

Comment: I miss Jobs, Tim Cook Ruined everything good from apple, If I need to clean my MacBook keyboard I need to open a notepad to be able to clean my keyboard or for another example, I don't want to turn on my MacBook to clean the screen but they force to start the mac, this feature is so annoying.

Comment: I can confirm it does not work on a MacBook Air M1, 2020, but I've found a site that says it works on MacBook Pro M1. Can't confirm (https://iboysoft.com/howto/disable-macbook-boot-on-lid-open.html)

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini I am in the same boat. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini Not yet!

Comment: Doesn't work on M2 either. So far, this is the limitation for all Apple Silicon laptops.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed with my 2021 16-inch Apple Silicon M1 MacBook Pro that changing the *auto-boot* variable using the `nvram` command in Terminal will cause the computer to refuse to boot.

https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/21/system-management-and-nvram-on-m1-macs/

If this happened to you, recovery is easy. Hold the power button during boot for "boot options" -> click "Options", then click "Continue". Choose a user, then click "Utilities" in the top menu, and open a new terminal.

https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/28/startup-modes-for-m1-macs/

The *default* value for *auto-boot* is "true". Setting this value in nvram can be done like this:

```
~ nvram -x auto-boot=%01
```

Listing values in nvram can be done like this:

```
~ nvram -x -p
```

Note: -x means use HEX to set and show values.