# How to disable M1 Mac auto-boot on lid open?

Tags: macos, startup, nvram, apple-silicon

There have been [answers that describe how this can be prevented for Intel Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381628/66411) using an NVRAM setting, but this `AutoBoot` setting has no effect on an M1 Mac. There is a similar `auto-boot` setting in the M1 Mac NVRAM list, which is set to `true` by default, but setting it to `false` or `%00` will cause the Mac to be unbootable. I have not found a way to prevent boot when the lid is open on an M1 Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Apple team didn't add the feature of turning off the autoboot for M1/M2 Chip MacBook(s) although it was there in Intel Chip MacBook(s) partially. You have to wait until any new update comes for **M1/M2 Chip** which includes turning off the autoboot.

**Otherwise, you can't simply disable it for now.**

**Note:** I have the Intel chip Macbook Pro 2019 in which you can disable the autoboot partially that disables the auto booting up when lid is opened only. But there is a limitation to that. If you press any key or touch the trackpad, it will start booting up which is kind of annoying.

Comment: No success yet.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the `sudo nvram auto-boot=false`, checked if it registered by `sudo nvram -p` and it said the value is `false`. Rebooted and the computer was unusable, could not even try to reset vram, the computer just showed an exclamation mark and a web address for apple support. Looking at on-line documentation it said I needed to "revive" or "restore" the computer by connecting it to another Apple silicon computer. Went to an Apple center where they told me I had to erase and restore the machine. Came back home, booted in recovery mode and made a last attempt before erasing the computer: pressed the hard disk icon to boot from the internal HD and everything worked again.

Lesson learnt? Always try the simplest things first, before getting into esoterics.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do a full restore if you mess up nvram values. You can boot into recovery mode and set your nvram to the previous value using the terminal, and your mac should boot as it did before. Apple support usually provides a one-size-fits-all solution to make things simple for them and because they often don't know as much as they really should.